# Responsive website "trapping" scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: ios, css, mobile, scroll, responsive-design

So, this is a problem I've never encountered, so pardon me if I have a bit of trouble explaining it.

What's happening is, on *some* mobile devices (possibly iOS only? I can't replicate it on my Android), when attempting to scroll past a certain point on the homepage, the screen stops, preventing scrolling below it, but if you let go of the screen and swipe again, you'll scroll past it normally. If you go back to the top of the screen, it'll "trap" again, and you need to swipe twice to get past the point again. As I said, I can't replicate this on my phone, or my browser's mobile site emulation, but I've seen it happen on an iPhone (5 I think. Maybe 5s)

[Here](https://www.l4sb.com/)'s a link to the site. What could be causing this?

Comment: Without looking to deep I think you may want to start out looking into the `jquery.inview` plugin you are using. I know from experience that javascript that attaches itself to scroll events can cause iOS browsers to lockup (or "trap" as you are calling it). Again, not sure if this is the issue, but it would be a good place to start looking

Comment: Checked on an Apple iPhone5s, didn't get trapped at all.